# Normalize and transpose data efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to normalize and transpose stock market data according to each symbol and I have created this method, but I see the loop inside the function  so slow. Is there any way to make it faster or do it in better way?

The function is:

```
normalize <- function(data, col){
    norm <- function(x){
        ((x - min(x))/ (max(x) - min(x)))
    }
    symbols <- t(unique(data['Symbol']))
    result <- data.frame()

    for (s in symbols)
        result <- rbind(result, norm(data[which(data['Symbol'] == s) , col]))
    result = cbind(t(symbols), result)
    colnames(result) <- c('Symbol', paste0('D', t(unique(data['Date']))))
    rownames(result) <- NULL
    return(result)
}
```

And console results are:

```
> r = normalize(allData, 'Close')
> head(allData, 20) # allData is the input data frame for the function

   Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume Adj.Close Symbol
   1     1 41.18 41.31 40.37 40.56 1529200  40.35932      A
   2     2 40.32 40.46 39.70 39.80 2041800  39.60308      A
   3     3 39.81 40.02 39.02 39.18 2080600  38.98615      A
   4     4 39.52 39.81 39.29 39.70 3359700  39.50358      A
   5     5 40.24 40.98 40.18 40.89 2116300  40.68769      A
   6     6 41.00 41.00 40.29 40.59 1643900  40.38917      AA
   7     7 40.61 40.72 39.95 40.11 2770800  39.91155      AA
   8     8 40.47 40.70 39.33 39.55 2013100  39.35432      AA
   9     9 39.03 39.10 38.21 39.06 5134000  38.86674      AA
   10   10 39.06 39.41 37.99 38.01 2628900  37.82194      AA
   11   11 37.83 38.46 37.76 38.25 3004000  38.06075      AAL
   12   12 38.43 38.66 37.76 37.93 5033600  37.74233      AAL
   13   13 37.75 38.41 37.68 38.16 2721600  37.97120      AAL
   14   14 38.51 39.86 38.12 39.65 4856600  39.45382      AAL
   15   15 39.60 39.60 38.76 38.81 1519300  38.61798      AAL
   16   16 38.79 39.17 38.47 39.15 1510900  38.95630      AAP
   17   17 38.70 39.25 38.58 38.75 1703500  38.55828      AAP
   18   18 39.01 39.05 37.96 38.00 2033500  37.81199      AAP
   19   19 38.00 38.47 37.69 38.46 2330000  38.26971      AAP
   20   20 38.01 38.32 37.71 37.77 3054300  37.58313      AAP

> head(r, 4)
    A 1.898358 1.138356 0.518357 1.038358 2.228356
   AA 1.928357 1.448358 0.888356 0.398358 -0.651645
  AAL -0.411643 -0.731643 -0.501643 0.988359 0.148358
  AAP 0.488359 0.08835696 -0.661643 -0.201644 -0.891643
```

A portion of the actual data:

```
> dput(allData)
structure(list(Date = 2:20, Open = c(40.32, 39.81, 39.52, 40.24, 
41, 40.61, 40.47, 39.03, 39.06, 37.83, 38.43, 37.75, 38.51, 39.6, 
38.79, 38.7, 39.01, 38, 38.01), High = c(40.46, 40.02, 39.81, 
40.98, 41, 40.72, 40.7, 39.1, 39.41, 38.46, 38.66, 38.41, 39.86, 
39.6, 39.17, 39.25, 39.05, 38.47, 38.32), Low = c(39.7, 39.02, 
39.29, 40.18, 40.29, 39.95, 39.33, 38.21, 37.99, 37.76, 37.76, 
37.68, 38.12, 38.76, 38.47, 38.58, 37.96, 37.69, 37.71), Close = c(39.8, 
39.18, 39.7, 40.89, 40.59, 40.11, 39.55, 39.06, 38.01, 38.25, 
37.93, 38.16, 39.65, 38.81, 39.15, 38.75, 38, 38.46, 37.77), 
    Volume = c(2041800L, 2080600L, 3359700L, 2116300L, 1643900L, 
    2770800L, 2013100L, 5134000L, 2628900L, 3004000L, 5033600L, 
    2721600L, 4856600L, 1519300L, 1510900L, 1703500L, 2033500L, 
    2330000L, 3054300L), Adj.Close = c(39.60308, 38.98615, 39.50358, 
    40.68769, 40.38917, 39.91155, 39.35432, 38.86674, 37.82194, 
    38.06075, 37.74233, 37.9712, 39.45382, 38.61798, 38.9563, 
        38.55828, 37.81199, 38.26971, 37.58313), Symbol = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "AA", "AAL", "AAP"), class = "factor")),     .Names = c("Date", 
"Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adj.Close", "Symbol"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: I think your `norm` function should be 
`norm <- function(x){
        (x - min(x))/( max(x) - min(x))
    }`

Comment: Oh thanks this is stupid mistake. I fixed it now

Comment: Can you add your data as well (with `dput`)?

Comment: The data is too big this is just a small portion of it

Comment: I understand, you could output just that portion it would be easier for us

Comment: Sorry for late reply but it took me a little while till I figured out how to get a portion of data and I put the full data file here https://github.com/pollaeng/FSPD

Comment: Thank you, however the first row is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function with this one:

```
normalize <- function(data, col){
norm <- function(x){
    ((x - min(x))/ (max(x) - min(x)))
}
symbols <- t(unique(data['Symbol']))

listSymbols<-lapply(symbols,function(s){
    norm(data[as.character(data$Symbol) == s , col])
})
symbolsValue<-as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(listSymbols),nrow=length(symbols)))
symbolsValue$Symbol<-t(symbols)

symbolsValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem of efficiency did not solved much as my code takes 1.51s while yours 1.33s is there any other way to make it really efficient

Comment: An edit has been made, now should be considerably faster

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be exactly what you are looking for it does provide flexibility in allowing a non equal number of entries per symbol.  The output is a list of arrays for the normalized values

```
 library(dplyr)
normalize<- function(data, col) {
      norm <- function(x){
        ((x - min(x))/ (max(x) - min(x)))
      }
      sym=unique(data$Symbol)
      r<-sapply(sym, FUN=function(x) {norm(select(filter(data, Symbol==x), one_of(col)))})
      names(r)<-sym
      r
    }

 df<-read.csv("test.csv")  #Your data goes here
 r<-normalize(df, "Close")  #Substitute column of interest here
```

Comment: I am trying to benchmark that function and it's highly inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I am not really happy about the sub-setting.  Can you post a comparison between the 3 methods?

Comment: `Unit: microseconds
                            expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 normalize_adiana(data, "Close")  381.724  422.9755  498.7788  454.555  519.491  961.216   100  a 
 normalize_dave2e(data, "Close") 2809.829 2978.7820 3447.4167 3136.287 3398.796 9347.279   100   b`